# Insert hyperlink to a local folder in Excel with Python

Tags: python, excel, hyperlink

The piece of code reads an Excel file.  This excel file holds information such as customer job numbers, customer names, sites, works description ect..

What this code will do when completed (I hope) is read the last line of the worksheet (this is taken from a counter on the worksheet at cell 'P1'), create folders based on cell content, and create a hyperlink on the worksheet to open the lowest local folder that was created.

I have extracted the info I need from the worksheet to understand what folders need to be created, but I am not able to write a hyperlink to the cell on the row in column B.

```
#Insert Hyperlink to folder
def folder_hyperlink(last_row_position, destination):
    cols = 'B'
    rows = str(last_row_position)
    position = cols + rows
    final_position = "".join(position)
    print final_position # This is just to check the value
    # The statement below should insert hyperlink in eps.xlsm > worksheet jobnoeps at column B and last completed row.
    ws.cell(final_position).hyperlink = destination
```

The complete code is below but here is the section that is meant to create the hyperlink.  I have also tried the 'xlswriter' package with no joy.  Searched the internet and the above snippet is the result of what I found.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
 __author__ = 'Paul'

import os
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import xlsxwriter

site_info_root = 'C:\\Users\\paul.EPSCONSTRUCTION\\PycharmProjects\\Excel_Jobs\\Site Information\\'

# This function returns the last row on eps.xlsm to be populated
def get_last_row(cell_ref = 'P1'): #P1 contains the count of the used rows
    global wb
    global ws
    wb = load_workbook("eps.xlsm", data_only = True) #Workbook
    ws = wb["jobnoeps"] #Worksheet
    last_row = ws.cell(cell_ref).value #Value of P1 from that worksheet
    return last_row


# This function will read the job number in format EPS-XXXX-YR
def read_last_row_jobno(last_row_position):
    last_row_data = []
    for cols in range(1, 5):
        last_row_data += str(ws.cell(column = cols, row = last_row_position).value)
    last_row_data_all = "".join(last_row_data)
    return last_row_data_all


#This function will return the Customer
def read_last_row_cust(last_row_position):
    cols = 5
    customer_name = str(ws.cell(column = cols, row = last_row_position).value)
    return customer_name


#This function will return the Site
def read_last_row_site(last_row_position):
    cols = 6
    site_name = str(ws.cell(column = cols, row = last_row_position).value)
    return site_name


#This function will return the Job Discription
def read_last_row_disc(last_row_position):
    cols = 7
    site_disc = str(ws.cell(column = cols, row = last_row_position).value)
    return site_disc


last_row = get_last_row()
job_no_details = read_last_row_jobno(last_row)
job_customer = read_last_row_cust(last_row)
job_site = read_last_row_site(last_row)
job_disc = read_last_row_disc(last_row)

cust_folder = job_customer
job_dir = job_no_details + "\\" + job_site + " - " + job_disc


#Insert Hyperlink to folder
def folder_hyperlink(last_row_position, destination):
    cols = 'B'
    rows = str(last_row_position)
    position = cols + rows
    final_position = "".join(position)
    print final_position # This is just to check the value
    # The statement below should insert hyperlink in eps.xlsm > worksheet jobnoeps at column B and last completed row.
    ws.cell(final_position).hyperlink = destination



folder_location = site_info_root + job_customer + "\\" + job_dir


print folder_location # This is just to check the value
folder_hyperlink(last_row, folder_location)
```

---

Now my hyperlink function looks like this after trying xlsxwriter as advised.

```
##Insert Hyperlink to folder
def folder_hyperlink(last_row_position, destination):
    import xlsxwriter
    cols = 'B'
    rows = str(last_row_position)
    position = cols + rows
    final_position = "".join(position)
    print final_position # This is just to check the value
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('eps.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('jobnoeps')
    print worksheet
    worksheet.write_url(final_position, 'folder_location')
    workbook.close()
```

The function overwrites the exsisting eps.xlsx, creates a jobnoeps table and then inserts the hyperlink.  I have played with the following lines but don't know how to get it to open the existing xlsx and existing jobnoeps tab and then enter the hyperlink.

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('eps.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('jobnoeps')
worksheet.write_url(final_position, 'folder_location')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XlsxWriter [`write_url()`](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-url) method allows you to link to folders or other workbooks and worksheets as well as internal links and links to web urls. For example:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('links.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.set_column('A:A', 50)

# Link to a Folder.
worksheet.write_url('A1', r'external:C:\Temp')

# Link to a workbook.
worksheet.write_url('A3', r'external:C:\Temp\Book.xlsx')

# Link to a cell in a worksheet.
worksheet.write_url('A5', r'external:C:\Temp\Book.xlsx#Sheet1!C5')

workbook.close()
```

See the docs linked to above for more details.

Comment: I've updated my first post.  Made some progress with xlsxwriter.

Comment: XlsxWriter can't update existing files. It wasn't clear to me that you were updating an existing file. I would recommend openpyxl for that but I don't think it supports hyperlinks to a folder.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that did the trick:-

```
# Creates hyperlink in existing workbook...

def set_hyperlink():
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    x = "hyperlink address"
    wb = load_workbook("filename.xlsx")
    ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name("sheet_name")
    ws.cell(row = x?, column = y?).hyperlink = x
    wb.save("filename.xlsx")

set_hyperlink()
```

Tried again with openpyxl as advised.